# How to add progress bar to aggregatations/reassignments performed within data.table brackets?

Tags: r, csv, progress-bar, data.table

I am writing a script for reading in large .csv files to a single large data.table to perform clean-up and aggregation. The use of the data.table format to aggregate and read columns `as.POSIXct` has been great. Still, many of the processed take time. I would like to add progress bars to these aggregations/re-assignments.

My script:

```
library(data.table)

files_in <- choose.files()
temp <- lapply(files_in, function(x) fread(x, skip = 4))
big_table <- rbindlist(temp)
headers <- c("TIMESTAMP","RECORD","CO2","H2O",Solenoid","AvgCO2In","AVGH2OIn",
             "AvgCO2Out","AvgH2OOut","QIn_Avg","AirTempIN","AirTempOUT")
colnames(big_table) <- headers
big_table <- unique(big_table)
big_table <- big_table[order(RECORD)]
for(i in big_table) {
  big_table[, TIMESTAMP := as.POSIXct(TIMESTAMP, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")]
  setTxtProgressBar(txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 1, style = 3), i)}
```

The .csv files being read initially are large files each with a couple hundred thousand observations and the big table created is several million observations long. So, even the reassignment of the column "TIMESTAMP" takes several minutes. For these files the "TIMESTAMP" column is an ambigous timestamp being converted to `POSIXct` format. The only way I can think to show progress is with the last few lines:

```
for(i in big_table) {
  big_table[, TIMESTAMP := as.POSIXct(TIMESTAMP, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")]; 
  setTxtProgressBar(txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 1, style = 3), i)}
```

But this won't work. It gives the following error message:

```
 Error in rep.int(char, nb) : invalid 'times' value
```

I have also dropped the for loop and tried this:

```
setTxtProgressBar(txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 1, style = 3), 
big_table[, TIMESTAMP := as.POSIXct(TIMESTAMP, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")])
```

It does not work. I have several other subsequent aggregations that I need to perform such as:

```
big_file_minute <- big_file[, lapply( .SD, mean), by = TIMESTAMP]
```

Of course, I would like to add progress bars here as well. I realize that my script may be off in many ways but a little advice will go a long way.

Thank you!

Comment: Try set instead of := for assignment in a loop and try if package anytime is faster for the time parsing.

Comment: @Roland I will keep this in mind as I refine this script. My plan-- at the moment-- is to put most of the data cleaning procedure I intend to implement into one single for loop and just attach a progress bar to the whole thing

Comment: I should also mention that I do not want to loop. I just cannot figure out how to attach a progress bar to something with no iterations. The use of `:=` and `lapply` within the data.table structure has been really fast for me.

Comment: I would concentrate on improving performance instead of implementing a progress bar. However, `lapply` is a loop and it should be possible to implement a progress bar within it.